# how to remove back slashes from json output in php

Tags: php, json, api

The code I have used:

```
$val = json_encode(array("test"=>test1,"test2" =>test,"description" => description));
return $val;
```

The result im getting

```
{\"test\":\"test1\",\"test2\":\"test\",\"description\":\"description\"}
```

I need this to fix api

Comment: From where do u get this output? I mean the php script. Could you show us that code

Comment: this is just a sample output.I need to remove the back slashes

Comment: But the point is, where are you getting the top one from? A JSON Decode? An API? Because that could effect the answer

Comment: @Aparna If it is the issue of the code or it happens when you assign the json value then its better to solve it at the begining rather than at the end using stripslashes()...

Comment: What do you **expect**? What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 26):

Try with `stripslashes()`

```
echo stripslashes('{\"test\":{\"test1\":{\"test1\":[{\"test2\":\"1\",\"test3\": \"foo\",\"test4\":\"bar\",\"test5\":\"test7\"}]}}}');
```

[stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Answer (score 13):

Tried this.

```
$val = json_encode(array(
  "test"=>'test1',
  "test2" =>'test',
  "description" => 'description'
));

$data = json_decode($val, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
return $data;
```

**This is the result I received.**

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21341430)

Comment: Thanks. I have added more detail for the answer.

Comment: Your answer worked for me, Thanks @KajornjitSongsaen

Answer (score 8):

In php "stripslashes" function is present using that you can remove backslash.

**[Link for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)**.

**Example:**

```
echo $strnew = stripslashes('{\"test\":{\"test1\":{\"test1\":[{\"test2\":\"1\",\"test3\": \"foo\",\"test4\":\"bar\",\"test5\":\"test7\"}]}}}');
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `stripslashes()` And read [stripslashes](http://php.net/strip_slashes)

```
<?php
$srt="'{\"test\":{\"test1\":{\"test1\":[{\"test2\":\"1\",\"test3\": \"foo\",\"test4\":\"bar\",\"test5\":\"test7\"}]}}}'
";
echo stripslashes($srt);
```

OUTPUT

> '{"test":{"test1":{"test1":[{"test2":"1","test3":
>   "foo","test4":"bar","test5":"test7"}]}}}'

Comment: I used a combination of your answer and the following answer - json_decode(stripslashes($val), true, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); - thank you

Answer (score 5):

you can use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

```
json_encode($yourjson, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use string find and replace function

```
$str="{"test":{"test1":{"test1":[{"test2":"1","test3": "foo","test4":"bar","test5":"test7"}]}}}";

str_replace("\'","'",$str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. It works perfectly fine for me `$cha` a string with backslashes

```
$cha = "{\"ashen\":\"143\"}";
$chachi = json_decode($cha,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
return $chachi['ashen'];
```

```
output: 143
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't think there is much to explain.  When there are "\" in a JSON object that means it's encoded so, what was done is simply use the pre-built-in PHP method json_decode to decode the JSON Object thus giving a pretty print

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing it. Is there anything special in your code? Or anything else that has not been provided in other answers?

Comment: ....especially, as the OP asked how to remove the slashes, not how to decode the string

Answer (score 1):

Actually, only Khachornchit Songsaen answer is correct.

`stripslashes` does not work on unescaping escaped " in json encoded strings inside another json.

es.

```
{ "key1" :"value1", "key2": "{\"key\":\"Text \\\"text\\\" text\"}" }
```

using `json_decode($var, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)` does the job correctly.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right method when your result is coming in slashes do this

```
    $data = [
        "message" => '',
        "data" => $product
    ];
    $response[] = $data;
    return $response;
```

do this it's really work because after 5 day i fund this solution or it is right .

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same issue, it is resolved by using **echo and exit;**

> $response = json_encode(array("test"=>"test1","test2"
> =>"test","description" => "description"));

> ```
> echo $response;
> exit;
> ```