# Why doesn't json_encode($arr) not return a true string?

Tags: php, laravel

Instead of this `"{\"name\":\"Shares Magazine\"}"` I want this `{"name":"Shares Magazine"}`.

To achieve this, I am doing this `json_encode(["name" => $user->reference_source], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

To no avail, as this always ends up in the database `"{\"name\":\"Shares Magazine\"}"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove back slashes from json output in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253267/how-to-remove-back-slashes-from-json-output-in-php)

Comment: Doesn't work as it still appears as `"{\"name\":\"Press\"}"` and I want it to appear as it says in OP

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using a `json` type column in your database

```php
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->json('json_column');
});
```

And you're also casting in your model

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'json_column' => 'json',
    ];
}
```

Then you don't need to cast before saving. Otherwise you're ending with a double cast. Laravel does that for you.

```php
Article::create([
    'json_column' => ['name' => 'Shares Magazine'],
]);
```

And it be will saved as `{"name": "Shares Magazine"}`.

Comment: Thank you I actually spotted it too

Answer (score 0):

Try this after encoding your JSON (this works better than `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`):

```
$json = preg_replace('/\\\"/',"\"", $json);
```